# Error about JVM when trying to run an Android project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I downloaded and configured Java SDK 7 and I have a 64-bit machine (I am pretty sure). The processor is Intel Core i7

But when I tried to run an Android app, I got this error:

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
```

Should I uninstall Java7 and go back to Java6? Or is something else wrong here?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the Java 8 SDK? Or in general the newest SDK?

Comment: Many of the suggestions in that link say that AndroidStudio is not compatible with Java8

Comment: Btw, I am on a mac so I can't implement the solution suggested in that link :(

Comment: Also, if my machine is 64 bit, then what exactly should I change in my setup that is the problem? Should I reinstall Java?